# Why is the CSS class and jQuery getting stuck when moving the cursor quickly over targeted selector when using .hover(), .addClass() & .removeClass()?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, hover

I created an `h1` element that gets a class added to it and removed from it with a duration of 300ms when the mouse hovers over and off of it's containing DIV `#logo` using **jQuery**'s `.hover()` method in concert with **jQuery UI**'s `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` methods.

It works splendidly but only when the user hovers over `#logo` and stops to wait for .addClass() method to complete adding the new class to the `h1` which takes 300 milliseconds total. If however the user moves off of the `#logo` DIV before the `.addClass()` method's 300 milliseconds are up, the jQuery `.addClass()` or `.removeClass()` method(s) get(s) paralyzed. Trying to move the cursor back into the `#logo` does not affect the `h1` anymore. It is locked into place for good until a browser refresh. Unacceptable.

You can view and try out [my example at JS Bin over here *](http://jsbin.com/oxano3/6/edit).

Try hovering over the `#logo` DIV box in the center of the screen slowly, you know, wait for the animation to complete. Then move the cursor off of it. All is well. Now try to just move the cursor quickly over the `#logo` DIV and you will see it lock up.

What code changes do I have to make in order to get this jQuery lock up from occurring?

**EDIT:** @pointy pointed me in the right direction. I got it to stop locking up by applying `.stop(true,true)` before the `.addClass('hover',300)` as well as applying it before the `.removeClass('hover',300)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick a "stop" call in before the "removeClass":

```
$('h1').stop(true, true).removeClass('hover', 300);
```

That jQuery UI class animation stuff is tricky.

Comment: well it definetly performs better. i can move the cursor over and off the #logo div fairly fast and get expected results but sometimes when i move it over and off it fast, i get the same lock up happening. what else could be wrong?

Comment: I got it behaving properly just now by adding .stop(true,true) before .addClass('hover', 300) too. thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: OK cool - I wasn't moving my mouse very aggressively I guess :-)